# ExactTarget REST API - using javascript to get accessToken

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, rest-api, ajax, fuel

With the clientId and clientSecret, is there a way to use JavaScript to get the accessToken through ajax?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using node.js, you can do so by using the [Node.js client](https://github.com/ExactTarget/node-fuel) for  ExactTarget's Fuel REST APIs.

```
var fuel = require('fuel').configure({
    authUrl: 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken',
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
});
```

Comment: Can I just have it as pure client side without relying on server (in this case, nodejs)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use a jquery.post to https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken with your clientId and clientSecret in the payload.  The result will contain your oauth token.

Comment: Hi Timothy, thanks for your answer but I tried that using jquery ajax, what I get in return is cross origin error but the network transaction is 200 OK, do you have any code sample that I can look at?